# Why z-index is not working on elements with position absolute?

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is when modal is opened to make the backdrop active so I cant click anywhere else
except on modal thats why it has z-index 10  and backdrop has z-index 5 but still the backdrop is covering the modal?

I have this structure of my html

```css
.layout {
  position: relative;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 5;
}

.course-area {
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class='backdrop'></div>
  <header class='header'>...</header>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <div class=' move-up '>
    <section class='banner '>...</section>
    <div class='features '>...</div>
    <div class='course-area '>
      <div class='modal '>...</div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` works with elements in the same level. You need to set correct `z-index` to `.move-up` in this case

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Are you sure? I just tried that  with an example and it worked fine

Comment: <style>
        .d1{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .d2 div{
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            z-index: 3;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='d1'></div>
    <div class="d2">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body> on this example  div element under div with class d2 is working fine

Comment: the backdrop isn't covering the modal but the modal start right below it, there is no overlap between both

Comment: the backdrop is actually covering modal because  modal normally is white and backdrop has a background rgba (0,0,0,0.5) and it is  above modal as well and modal is not clickable @TemaniAfif

Comment: actually that is a react app and I get that structure after I run the app I don't think it has any difference but if someone thinks it is I can post my components

Comment: share a more complete code with content. Using dots as content will not help us see and reproduce the issue